# Delete row by row or a bulk

Tags: php, mysql, performance, delete-row

I would like like to delete a bulk of data. this table have approximately 11207333 now

However I have several method to delete it.

The data that will be deleted is approximately 300k. I have two method to do this but unsure which one perform faster.

My first option:

```
$start_date     = "2011-05-01 00:00:00";
$end_date       = "2011-05-31 23:59:59";
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE date>='$start_date' and date <='$end_date'";
$mysqli->query($sql);
printf("Affected rows (DELETE): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows);
```

second option:

```
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM table WHERE date>='$start_date' and date <='$end_date'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$total = $row['count'];

if ($total > 0) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date>='$start_date' and date <='$end_date' LIMIT 0,$total";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
      while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $table_id = $row['table_id']; // primary key
            $query = "DELETE FROM table where table_id = $table_id LIMIT 0,$total";
            $mysqli->query($query);

    }
}
```

This table data is displayed to client to see, I afraid that if the deletion go wrong and it will affect my client.

I was wondering are there any method better than mine.

If you guys need more info from me just let me know.

Thank you

Comment: method 1 looks good. I don't see any deletion in method 2.

Comment: Oops sorry sir i copy the wrong query i can ensure with you that the second option query is deletion

Comment: If the code in the second block of code is wrong, perhaps you could update your question to include the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the first option is faster.

The second option contains looping which I think will be slower because it keeps looping several times looking for your table id.

If you did not provide the wrong start and end date, I think you're safe either option, but option 1 is faster in my opinion.

and yea, i dont see any deletion in option 2, but I assume you have it in mind but using looping method.

Comment: Oops sorry sir i copy the wrong query i can ensure with you that the second option query is deletion

Answer (score 0):

Option one is your best bet.

If you are afraid something will "go wrong" you could protect yourself by backing up the data first, exported the rows you plan to delete, or implementing a logical delete flag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is indeed a DELETE query in it, the second method is not only slower, it may break if another connection deletes one of the rows you intend to delete in your `while` loop, before it had a chance to do it. For it to work, you need to wrap it in a transaction:

```
mysqli_query("START TRANSACTION;");
# your series of queries...
mysql_query("COMMIT;");
```

This will allow the correct processing of your queries in *isolation* of the rest of the events happening in the db.

At any rate, if you want the first query to be faster, you need to tune your table definition by adding an index on the column used for the deletion, namely `` `date` `` (however, recall that this new index may amper other queries in your app, if there are already several indexes on that table).

Without that index, mysql will basically process the query more or less the same way as in method 2, but without:

- PHP interpretation,
- network communication and
- query analysis overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `SELECTS` to make the delete in a loop. Just use `LIMIT` in your delete query and check if there are affected rows:

```
$start_date     = "2011-05-01 00:00:00";
$end_date       = "2011-05-31 23:59:59";
$deletedRecords = 0;
$sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE date>='$start_date' and date <='$end_date' LIMIT 100";
do {
$mysqli->query($sql);
$deletedRecords += $mysqli->affected_rows;
while ($mysqli->affected_rows > 0);
}

printf("Affected rows (DELETE): %d\n", $deletedRecords);
```

Which method is better depends on the storage engine you are using.

If you are using InnoDB, this is the recommended way. The reason is that the DELETE statement runs in a transaction (even in auto-commit mode, every sql statement is run in a transaction, in order to be atomic... if it fails in the middle, the whole delete will be rolled back and you won't end with half-data). Which means that you will have a long running transaction, and you will have a lot of locked rows during the transaction, which will block anyone who wants to update such data (it can block insterts if there are unique indexes involved) and reads will be done via the rollback log. In other words, for InnoDB, large deletes are faster if performed in chunks.

In MyISAM however, the delete locks the entire table. If you do in lot of small chunks, you will have too many LOCK/UNLOCK commands executed, which will actually slow the process. I would make it in a loop for MyISAM as well, to give chance to other processes to use the table, but in larger chunks compared to InnoDB. I would never do it row by row for MyISAM based table because of the LOCK/UNLOCK overhead.